# Convert array in objects to individual strings

Tags: javascript

How can I split an `array` of `images` among an `object`?

For example, using the **JSON** below. How can produce a `return` `string` of each `itemUrl` and it's associated `productCode`?

**This JSON**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productCode": "ID1",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/1.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/2.JPG"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productCode": "ID2",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/3.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/4.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/5.JPG"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Becomes**

```
https://img.com/1.JPG
https://img.com/2.JPG
https://img.com/3.JPG
https://img.com/4.JPG
https://img.com/5.JPG
```

Currently, if I were to use

```
for (const tour of data.products) {
  console.log(tour.images[0].itemUrl);
  ...
```

the return would obviously `return`

```
https://img.com/1.JPG
https://img.com/3.JPG
```

however, when

```
let imageEach = tour.images;
let output = [];
imageEach.forEach(item => {
  output.push(item.itemUrl);
});
  ...
```

I get a `return` of

```
[{
  https://img.com/1.JPG,
  https://img.com/2.JPG
}]

[{
  https://img.com/3.JPG
  https://img.com/4.JPG
  https://img.com/5.JPG
}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this using `Array.reduce` to iterate over the products and `Array.map` to go through the items and get the `itemUrl`:

```js
const data = { "products": [ { "productCode": "ID1", "images": [ { "id": 1, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/1.JPG" }, { "id": 2, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/2.JPG" } ] }, { "productCode": "ID2", "images": [ { "id": 3, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/3.JPG" }, { "id": 4, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/4.JPG" }, { "id": 5, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/5.JPG" } ] } ] } 

const result = data.products.reduce((r,{images}) => {
  r.push(...images.map(x => x.itemUrl))
  return r
}, [])
 console.log(result.join('\n'))
```

Or even shorter as suggested by @Prassana by using ES6 array spread some more:

```js
const data = { "products": [ { "productCode": "ID1", "images": [ { "id": 1, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/1.JPG" }, { "id": 2, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/2.JPG" } ] }, { "productCode": "ID2", "images": [ { "id": 3, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/3.JPG" }, { "id": 4, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/4.JPG" }, { "id": 5, "itemUrl": "https://img.com/5.JPG" } ] } ] } 

const result = data.products.reduce((r,{images}) => 
  [...r, ...images.map(x => x.itemUrl)], [])

console.log(result.join('\n'))
```

Comment: since you have already used rest operators what is the point of push here ? you can simple `return [...r, ...images.map(x => x.itemUrl) ]`

Comment: Very good point. No reason other than hobbit and trying to type quick :). Will update. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much but this still returns as an `array` rather than individual `strings`. Reading back at my question, it perhaps is not the clearest.

Comment: I mean you can join and have it as string etc. See updated answer. You can also simply spread the array `console.log(...result)`

Comment: Thank you. It does what I asked for, unlikely to work in my issue but I should have been more detailed in my questioning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.products[i].images.length; j++){
        result.push(data.products[i].images[j].itemUrl);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Array.concat`

```js
const data = {
  "products": [
    {
      "productCode": "ID1",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/1.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/2.JPG"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productCode": "ID2",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/3.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/4.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/5.JPG"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let urls =  []
data.products.forEach(item => {
  urls = urls.concat(item.images.map(img => img.itemUrl))
})

console.log(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```js
let json = {
  "products": [
    {
      "productCode": "ID1",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/1.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/2.JPG"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productCode": "ID2",
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/3.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/4.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "itemUrl": "https://img.com/5.JPG"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
json.products.forEach(product => {
     console.log(product.productCode + ": ")
     product.images.forEach(i => console.log(i.itemUrl))                       
});

// or 
json.products.forEach(product => {
     product.images.forEach(i => console.log(product.productCode + " : " + i.itemUrl))  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
products.reduce((urls, product, i) => {
  const imageURLs = product.images.map(img => img.itemUrl);
  urls = urls.concat(imageURLs);
  return urls;
}, []);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

**You can try my code to produce following result**

```
{
 "ID1" : ["https://img.com/1.JPG","https://img.com/2.JPG"],
 "ID2" : ["https://img.com/3.JPG","https://img.com/4.JPG","https://img.com/5.JPG"]
}
```

Below is the code. Lets take your mentioned JSON data as "obj"(a variable)

```
 obj.products.reduce((acc, product)=>{
   acc[product.productcode] = product.images.map(img => img.itemUrl)
   return acc
 }, {})
```